# Scroll to next page by mousewheel

Tags: jquery, html, css, wordpress, scroll

I need to change current page to another one by scrolling on mouse.

Imagine, normal function on Wordpress for change another post…prev_post and next_post. When you’ll use it in a template, you will get two links. One is previous post and second one next post. When you click on one of them you will be moved to the next or previous page. And I would need to happen the same thing by scrolling mousewheel.

Can anybody know how to do that?

Comment: You need to be a bit more precise. You can have *another* page on a  different URL or in the same document...

Comment: Can you share some code?

Comment: ok. Here is a website http://www-kodovani.cz/vc2/re/ . You can see the arrows on the right. When you click them you will listing between the posts. I would need to do the same effect by mousewheel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X7M7y/2/)**

```
var url = document.URL, // full page URL
    pages = [ "index.html", "about.html", "contact.html" ], // LIST OF PAGES
    // retrieve pagename and it it's "" means we're on index.html
    currPage  = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) || "index.html",    
    wheelAt = $.inArray(currPage, pages), // get 0,1,2,3
```

You can also use use [Brandon Aaron jQuery mouseWheel plugin](https://github.com/brandonaaron/jquery-mousewheel).

- you have the Number of the page in array when the browser loads
- On mousewheel change the value of: `wheelAt =` mousewheel up||down (-1, +1)
- than just go to `window.location = pages[ wheelAt ]`

Comment: I know.

It looks nice. Thanks

Comment: I've tried to use your code but it doesn't work right. You can check it here http://www-kodovani.cz/vc2/ahoj-vsichni/

Comment: @user2679576 I cannot find the code in your page... Any way, If you got it, what I explained in my answer, with a bit of easy tweaks from the posted and the code in my demo you'd get it working. A proof of concept is my online demo. you just need to implement that code with the explained above.

Comment: The problem is I really don't understand JS. Can you set it for me when I give you a ftp?

Comment: @user2679576 I'm sorry, I have no time to, I hop here and there on SO, but I don't think I'm paid to fix issues on the WWW. Don't get me wrong. Rather find a friend that knows a bit of JS and show him this answers, I'm sure he'll be able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

I would say something like:

```
$(window).bind("mousewheel DOMMouseScroll", function(e){
    var delta = parseInt(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -e.originalEvent.detail);
    if(delta > 0) {
        window.location.href = nextpage;
    } else {
        window.location.href = previouspage;
    }
});
```

Although that can be rather annoying but that is just my opinion.